# Entity class with DB showing Table with No primary key

Tags: java, sql-server, netbeans, ejb-3.0

I want to create an Entity class with database in Netbeans.

When I select a Data source jdbc/Ionbank (custom Jdbc connection Using JDBC-ODBC bridge with Ms SQL 2005 as database).

I see all the tables from that database.
All tables show no primary key, but they have primary keys in them.

Things I have tried :-

1. Created new 4-5 data source.
2. Created tables using query, and not the New table option.
3. Tried changing Odbc connection.
4. Tried using different drivers for the Jdbc-Odbc bridge like Sql4jdbc.jar, Jdts.jar.

Comment: The JDBC-ODBC bridge is not a recommended solution... have you tried to connect using MS SQL Server Connector?

Comment: Post your code / configuration files and exceptions thrown

Comment: Having problem With Ms Sql Server connector also(Different topic).

Comment: Cant show u code or exceptions thrown Bcoz i am doing this with Netbeans Ide interface,Using New File > Entity class with database option.

Comment: Thank you very much, @perissf! Your solution worked for me. I think it is better to write it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had same issue, but i solved it using the following: ["New Entity Classes from Database" cannot process some tables, saying "no primary key"](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=167389)

A quote from that link helped me:

> The problem will happen if you have foreign keys where upper case and lower case table names don't match the referenced table's definition.

For instance:

```
create table OkTable (
   id int not null auto_increment
   , primary key (id)
);

create table MisunderstoodTable(
   id int not null auto_increment
   oktable int not null
   , primary key (id)
   , foreign key ok (oktable) references oktable (id)
);
```

The `MisunderstoodTable` has a foreign key where the target table name doesn't match the lower/uppercase name of the referenced table.

To avoid this problem, just make sure you type your foreign key definitions while matching upper/lower casing for the targeted table.